# desCBC algorithm supported by BouncyCastle FIPS in non-approved mode?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, des, fips

Is the CMSAlgorithm.DES_CBC supported for encryption by BCFIPS provider ? In a standalone reproducer program, it seem to work fine while the following exception gets thrown in k8s-docker based environment. This occurs despite having the same versioned bc* jars in both the environments. Both the environments are having these properties set.

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());

System.setProperty("org.bouncycastle.fips.approved_only", "false");

System.setProperty("org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_pkcs15_enc", "true");

System.setProperty("org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_multi_use", "true");
```

Any clues on what could be the reason?

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.3.14.3.2.7 for provider BCFIPS

at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)

at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:127)

at java.base/javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:286)

at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createKeyGenerator(Unknown Source)

... 43 common
```

Standalone reproducer program works fine